# I want the character to walk not only in x but also in y

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, topdown

**I want the character to walk not only in x but also in y**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
        
        
public class Control : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed; // speed
    private float input; 
        
    private Rigidbody2D rb; // player
        
    public Animator anim; // player animator
    public Joystick joystick; // player joystick
        
    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        input = joystick.Vertical;
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(input * speed, rb.velocity.y);
    }
}
```

**I want the character to walk not only in x but also in y**

Comment: So you want it to fly? Try: float input2 = joystick.Horizontal; rb.velocity = new Vector2(input * speed, input2 * speed);

Comment: i want the character to go up and down, left and right with the joystick, i added your line of code but when i pull the joystick up it goes down and also left and right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To simply just make it work you could just modify your code like this:

```
private Vector3 change;
// Declare private property above functions

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    change.x = joystick.Horizontal;
    change.y = joystick.Vertical;
    change = change.normalized;
    rb.MovePosition(rb.transform.position + change * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
}
```

You are doing correctly that you're moving rb in FixedUpdate, but updating input would actually be better in normal update. So best option is:

```
private Vector3 change;
// Declare private property above functions

private void Update()
{
    change.x = joystick.Horizontal;
    change.y = joystick.Vertical;
    change = change.normalized; // Correct diagonal movement speed
}
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    rb.MovePosition(rb.transform.position + change * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
}
```

Also, in this case in 2D, I think that you must actually use Vector3 to make it work correctly with transform.position + rb.MovePosition().